# SSRS Invalid Character In XML

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've got an ssrs mobile report that when I try and open, it throws a generic error. Looking at the logs its complaining about hitting recursion limits. Simple fix, so I thought. The problem I have is that I don't seem to be able to find a way to view the offending query as it won't open in mobile report builder.

I've tried casting the Catalog content to VARBINARY(MAX) and then XML which fails due to an illegal xml character.

```
SELECT Name,
CAST(CAST(Content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS xml) AS ReportXML
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
where ItemID = 'AnId'
```

If I just cast to a VARCHAR(MAX) I get what looks like a chinese character.

䭐Ѓ

Is there any way to recover this or see whats actually being saved for the dataset query? I worry its somehow become corrupted and will have to be written again.
The only db backups I have all have the same issue. Frustratingly its been going on for a year and only been told today.

Comment: When I come across oddities like this, I will deconstruct the report part by part, starting with UI elements and then datasets and data sources. Most of the time it is something arcane to do with the data.

Comment: Is the `Type` of that item = 2 (Report)?

Comment: Thanks. The type of that report is 3. Unfortunately deconstructing the report isn't an option as I am unable to open any of the report builders due to the error.